# Discrepencies in Pandas groupby aggregates vs dataframe, particularly on axis=1

Tags: pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "b", "c", "k"],["d", "e", "f", "l"],['g','h','i', "J"]], columns=["ay", "be", "ce", "jay"])
    print(df)

    gb1 = df.groupby({"ay": "x", "be": "x"}, axis=1)
    gb2 = df.groupby({"ay": "x", "be": "x", "ce": "y", "jay": "y"}, axis=1)

    print("apply sum by axis 0")
    #print(df.apply(sum))
    print("fails")

    print("apply sum by axis 1")
    # print(df.apply(sum, axis=1))
    print("fails")

    print("agg sum by axis 0")
    print(df.agg(sum))

    print("agg sum by axis 1")
    print(df.agg(sum, axis=1))

    print("gb1 apply sum axis 1")
    print(gb1.apply(sum))

    print("gb1 agg sum axis 1")
    print(gb1.agg(sum))

    print("gb2 apply sum axis 1")
    # print(gb2.apply(sum))
    print("fails")

    print("gb2 agg sum axis 1")
    print(gb2.agg(sum))

    print(gb1.agg(lambda x: ";".join([x[0], x[1]]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I don't understand the failures occurring and I don't understand why apply on groups fails with 2 groups but not with one.

I've solved my overall goal (I was trying to concatenate some strings of columns together) but I am concerned that I am somewhat bewildered by these failures.

The driving goal for reference was to be able to do

```
gb1.agg(lambda x: ";".join(x))
```

and I also don't understand why that doesn't work

especially since

```
gb1.agg(lambda x: ";".join([x[0], x[1]]) does
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack in there.

```
    print("apply sum by axis 0")
    #print(df.apply(sum))
    print("fails")

    print("apply sum by axis 1")
    # print(df.apply(sum, axis=1))
    print("fails")
```

...the above are failing because you're *apply*-ing the Python sum function, which requires numerical types.  You could use either of the following to fix that (which I think under the hood relies on the ability of numpy to handle the object dtypes that pandas converts them to):

```
df.apply(np.sum)
df.sum()
```

---

Next, these two items say axis=1 in the print statement, but aren't really:

```
    print("gb1 apply sum axis 1")
    print(gb1.apply(sum))

    print("gb2 apply sum axis 1")
    # print(gb2.apply(sum))
    print("fails")
```

...if you add axis=1 they'll work and give sensible results.

---

Note that you have a missing closing parenthesis in:

```
gb1.agg(lambda x: ";".join([x[0], x[1]])
```

...both in the sample code and in the later comment about it.

It seems like you're saying that the final bit of code is what accomplishes your goal.  The previous attempt:

```
gb1.agg(lambda x: ";".join(x))
```

...is joining the items in the *index* of the one group that is present instead of the individual series. Examine:

```
print(gb1.groups)
```

---

Finally, given your dataframe if what you wanted to do was concatenate columns with ";" between them, you could also do:

```
cols = ['ay','be']
df.apply(lambda x: ";".join((x[c] for c in cols)), axis=1)
```

or for a small number of items,

```
df['concat'] = df['ay'] + ";" + df['be']
```

...rather than using groupby.

Comment: Ah, the groupby agg doesn't have axis but apply does. In general I'm a little confused about the difference between dataframes.[apply|agg|transform] and groupby.[apply|agg|transform]. Some of them have shared argument lists, some of them have similar behavior, some of them seem to be quite different and all of them seem to have some redundant functionality (i.e. doing an apply on a groupby of 1 group is similar to an apply on a column selection and you can both agg and apply sum)